# Realm Android: order by id-list

Tags: android, realm

How can I make sure a `RealmResult` is sorted based on the sort order of an ids integer array?

```
   public static RealmResults<ContentPage> getContentPages(Realm realm, Integer[] ids) {

        return realm.where(ContentPage.class)
               .in(ContentPage.FIELD_ID, ids).findAll();
   }
```

So I am looking for a way to sort the `ContentPage` objects, based on their id location in the ids array.

I am not converting this `RealmResult` to a list, it is an auto managed object and so I cannot run a normal `Comparator` on it after retrieval.

***EDIT**: If I try to use a normal comparator on a RealmResult, I'll get: UnsupportedOperationException: Replacing and element is not supported.

***EDIT 2**: My questions seems to be unclear: If I have an ids array like this: `[3,1,2]`. That goes into `.in(ContentPage.FIELD_ID, ids)` above. I would like the RealmResult to be in that order: item with id 3 first, 1 after that, 2 last.

***EDIT 3**: Fixed by creating a new ArrayList from the RealmResult every time it changes (use a Realm ChangeListener) and using that further in my app. You can sort this copied array. Not ideal, but a temporary solution.

```
List copiedList = new ArrayList<>(getPagesResult);
Collections.sort(copiedList, comparator);
```

Comment: but RealmResults already have the .sort() method so no need to convert to array, or i am totally lost and cant get you well xD

Comment: :) as you can see above, running the .sort() method of a RealmResult gives "UnsupportedOperationException: Replacing and element is not supported."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conclusion: It is not supported by Realm.

One can fix this by creating a new `ArrayList` from the `RealmResult` every time it changes (use a `RealmChangeListener`) and using that in the app. You can sort this copied array. Not ideal, but a working solution.

```
List copiedList = new ArrayList<>(getPagesResult);
Collections.sort(copiedList, comparator);
```

If you are using a `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` this won't work though, you need the `RealmResult` for that. Also, this solution takes away other niceties of using `RealmResults`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `findAll();` with `findAllSorted();` at the end of your query`

```
.findAllSorted(ContentPage.FIELD_ID, Sort.ASCENDING);
```

Comment: No, I'm looking for: "sorted based on the sort order of an ids integer array", so compared to the "in(...)" order. Ids might be sorted on anything

Answer (score 0):

just use findAllSorted:

```
return realm.where(ContentPage.class)
           .in(ContentPage.FIELD_ID, ids).findAllSorted("id",Sort.DESCENDING);
```

Comment: someone already posted this as answer. No need to say it again

Comment: well he was faster than me :D

Comment: No, I'm looking for: "sorted based on the sort order of an ids integer array", so compared to the "in(...)" order. Ids might be sorted on anything.

Comment: @Frank according to the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html) this will be fetched sorted and wont be sorted after fetching.

Comment: I updated my question, maybe that makes it more clear. Your answer would sort the result on the id integer, not on the sort order in the ids list.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly?

```
return realmResults.get(sortArray[i-1]-1);
```

Comment: that only retrieves one item?

Comment: As long as you have your "sort array" you can get any of them.

Comment: I would like to have the RealmResult sorted. Not copy the list, not take items out of it one by one and put them in a new list. Apparently you cannot sort it after the query finished, without copying into an new list, so I was looking for a way to update the query in such a way that it sorts the items on retrieval, in the query, bases on the id list. I guess it's not possible.

Comment: not unless you set a field's values to your sort order then do an ascending sort over that.